# Is there hotkey to bring up the network connections popup on Windows 7 and 8?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, hotkeys

My question is clear with an image:

[image]

Is there any hotkey to use instead of mouse clicking the network connection icon in the tray?

Without the hotkey, I have to press Win+B, right arrow several times, then Enter, very cumbersome.

That popup is impoooortant because when I want choose a Wifi SSID to connect, that seems to be the only GUI way.

---

Oh yes, as some veteran user points out, `rundll32.exe van.dll,RunVAN` is the right answer for me.

[image: The Windows 7 VAN popup]

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no Windows hotkey available but you can create it.

Please follow the below steps

(i) Go to ncpa.cpl file available in the C:/Windows/System32 and then right click on the file to create a shortcut on the desktop.

(ii)Now go to the desktop,Then right click on the created shortcut and go to the shortcut option.

(iii) Now enter cltrl + Alt + any character and save it.

Now you can use the hotkey to open the network connection

Comment: But ``ncpa.cpl`` command bring up a different user interface, one of which is ``ncpa.cpl`` window does not show Wifi SSID list, right?

Comment: Ok,Please follow the below steps,                                 Go to Start -> Control Panel ->Network and Internet and then right click on Network and Sharing Center and create a shortcut.          Now go to newly created shortcut,then right click and chose properties.                                                      Now press the key for shortcut.It would be set.So the shortcut key would be ctrl + alt + F as you wish.Once you press the button,the network connection pop up would open